# Downsides to indefinite replicate streaming delays?

Tags: postgresql

I have a db server that's sole purpose is for analytics querying. It's running as a hot standby, but long running queries are failing due to `max_standby_archive_delay` and `max_standby_streaming_delay` being reached.

I've read a few articles saying that setting these variables too high is "undesirable," presumably due to lagging in the replicant. If I don't really care about that, are there any other reasons to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `hot_standby_feedback` then there can be issues with WAL accumulation on the master. Otherwise there's no real problem if you don't mind your replica getting potentially indefinitely delayed.

I strongly recommend setting up WAL archiving if you haven't already.